# Shower valve identification

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve, renovation

I am trying to buy replacement handles for an old shower. It’s a 3-handle with 4 spline hot/cold and a 17 spline diverter.

I’m a bit in over my head here (no bathing puns intended) and I don’t know how to go about buying the right valve handles.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the old handles? If so, take them to a plumbing supply store. They should be able to fit you up with some that will work. If you don't have them, then take the valves and diverter out and bring them to the plumbing store. Might be a good idea to do that anyway and have the washers replaced. Are the covers and sleeves still in good shape? If not, bring them too.